# Symbol which looks like . (dot) but is classified as letter in unicode

Tags: .net-framework, unicode, spell-check, string, special-characters

Iam writing my bachelor thesis at the moment. The problem for me is now the spellchecker (I use Open Office but this is a general problem) won't recognize .NET as a valid word. A also cannot add it to a user specific dictionary because of the leading dot.
Also the grammar checker has a mayor problem with the dot.

I consider this a general problem with spell-checkers and grammar-checking software. If I recall correctly for a similar reason they invented a lowercase and a uppercase version of ß (German letter 'S-Z', Html entity: &szlig;) but which are both looking the same.

To make it short, is there a unicode symbol which looks like a dot but is classified as a letter symbol?

Comment: Although your thesis is about programming, this particular question is better suited for http://superuser.com.

Comment: I'd suggest using DotNet instead everywhere and then you could just do a global search and replace right before handing it in/printing it. Btw, I think this should probably be on superuser rather than stackoverflow.

Comment: OOo doesn't complain .NET for me.

Comment: I definitely wouldn't want to start including bogus characters in my documents just to satisfy a spell-checker. Spell-checkers are merely diagnostic tools to spot accidental mistakes: you can and should ignore them when you know you are right. It's a pointless task to try to author documents with zero spell-checker/grammar-checker reports.

Comment: @bobince: The problem is that so many bogus-errors let you oversee same real spelling errors. If I develop a program which compiles with thousands of warnings then the usefulness of warnings are senseless.

Comment: @KennyTM: Yes in english, net is actually a word. But the grammar with the dot is wrong. You aren't using the extension "languagetool" of open office?

Comment: "Spell-checking a programming related document is pointless": You can't be serious..

Comment: ".NET" is not actually a word.

Comment: Same problem here and no solution so far.

Answer (score 5):

According to the [punctuation chart](http://unicode.org/charts/PDF/U0080.pdf), "U+2024 ONE DOT LEADER" might be the right symbol fr your use case.

If there is a workaround, maybe using widely acknowledged DOTNet or dot.net, might be another discussion.

Comment: "DOTNet" would work whereas "dot.net" will suffer from the same problem

Comment: ASCII 8228.  I started using this character when posting sample java via Twitter. (Twitter was attempting to convert functions to clickable links.)